# Error: "Fill no es miembro de OleDbCommand"

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Estoy en visual basic, intentando realizar una conexión a una DB en access. Para contextualizar, el sistema esta funcionando con SQL, generando el String de datos de conexión, luego el objetos conexión y sus querys. El tema es que al tratar de hacer lo mismo, con access me arroja el error del encabezado, y es cuando debo mandar los datos al DataTable, estaban utilizando un .fill(). Aquí es donde me muestra el error. Error: "Fill no es miembro de OleDbCommand"

El código actual es el siguiente:

String de conexión.

```
Public connection As String = "data source = MARLI_SRV; initial catalog = BD_Evasiones; user id = sa; password = xxxxxxxxxx"
Public access_connection As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=\\C-186-PC\prueba\Evasiones 2017.accdb;"
```

Objetos de conexión.

```
'Public Conexion As New SqlConnection(connection)
Public Conexion As New OleDbConnection(access_connection)
```

Select a la base de datos.

```
'Dim dr As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * From Evasiones Order by NroExpedicion", Conexion)
Dim dr As New OleDbCommand("Select * From Evasiones", Conexion)
```

Pasar a DataTable

```
 Dim dz As New DataTable
 dr.Fill(dz)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que te muestra te indica que Fill no pertenece a la clase OleDbCommand.

Para poder hacer el Fill a un DataTable con OleDb necesita declarar OleDbDataAdapter que es la clase que contiene el Fill:

```
'Declaramos el OleDbCommand '
Dim cmm As New OleDbCommand("Select * From Evasiones", Conexion)

'Declaramos el OleDbDataAdapter '
Dim dr As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmm)

'Hacemos el Fill al DataTable '
dr.Fill(dz)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto me ayudo a resolver el problema que tenía!!